# Did Jesus mean Daniel 9:24 when he said to forgive seventy times seven?

Tags: prophecy

Was Jesus referring to Daniel 9:24 when He said to forgive till seventy times seven?

Matthew 18:22

> Jesus says to him, "I say to you not up to seven times, but up to **seventy times seven**!

Daniel 9:24

> **Seventy weeks** are decreed for your people and your holy city to stop their transgression, to put an end to sin, to make atonement for iniquity, to bring in everlasting righteousness, to seal up vision and prophecy, and to anoint the Most Holy

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: It seem unlikely this goes beyond *"Many times?" "No, much more than that!"*

Answer (score 2):

If Jesus, in Matt 18:22, intended to quote or allude to Dan 9:24, He did a very poor job - the two phrases are different.

- Matt 18:22 - ἑβδομηκοντάκις ἑπτά = seventy times seven
- Dan 9:24 (LXX which reflects the Hebrew well) - ἑβδομήκοντα ἑβδομάδες = seventy weeks

Note the different words and meanings involved here:

- ἑβδομηκοντάκις (70 times) vs ἑβδομήκοντα (= seventy)
- ἑπτά (seven singular) vs ἑβδομάδες (= weeks plural)
- In Matt 18, Jesus refers to the repetition of forgiveness, vs Dan 9 where Daniel refers to a period of time

Thus, the two are different phrases and refer to different things.

**Conclusion**

No, Jesus in Matt 18:22 is **not** alluding to Dan 9:24.

Some believe there may be a reference to Gen 4:24, but that would open a new question.

Comment: +1 They are definitely not even the same number.