Is my approch of translating Dan. 9.24 (MT), the more accurate method of translation; by including words that are doubled, or in parentheses?
עַל־ נֶחְתַּךְ שִׁבְעִים שָׁבֻעִים קָדְשֶׁךָ עִיר עַמְּךָ [ולחתם] הַפֶּשַׁע נֶחְתַּךְ (חַטָּאת) [חטאות] (וּלְהָתֵם) וּלְהָבִיא עָוֺן וּלְכַפֵּר חָזוֹןוְ לַחְתֹּם עֹלָמִים צֶדֶק קָדָשִׁים וְלִמְשֹׁחַ וְנָבִיא
Above is the Masoretic Text of Dan.9.24, as found on the "Bible tool" app ( as seen in the pic below); I have notice that is has several words that are not translated in the A.V; or the arrangement of the words are different, than in other versions I have found of the seeming Masoretic text; where details are exclude, like words that are doubled,  or that are in are in parentheses, or is some cases not being translated, or numbered.
So in my effort of rendering ever word, even if doubled, or in parentheses; it seems that the text has a more clearer sense when rendered with this approach; over against not rendering if not numbered, or wrongly identified as noted below.
Is there any reason for this exclusion of words, and wrongly numbering them; was it just an attempt to make sense of the text; but motivated by theological bias, and a faulty method of textual analysis; and in so doing, have wrested the scripture?
Dan.9.24:
there are H5921 עַל־ divided H2852 נֶחְתַּךְ seventy H7657 שִׁבְעִים weeks H7620 שָׁבֻעִים; for the holy H6944 קָדְשֶׁךָ city H5892 עִיר; and for your people H5971 עַמְּךָ, to end ולחתם (not numbered) the rebellion הַפֶּשַׁע 6588; and to restrain H3607 נֶחְתַּךְ the sin H2304 חַטָּאת.
These sins H2304 חטאות (is doubled in Heb., and wrongly numbered H2856) will be brought to an end H2856 וְלַחְתֹּם at the coming H935 וּלְהָבִיא punishment H5771 עָוֺן ; which will be for purging H3722, וּלְכַפֵּר cp. Dan.12.10).
וְנָבִיא This prophecy should be read in v25,
and is linked to the "some" מִן that shall have understanding.
I also noticed this happening in the Talmud. And looked up on torah.org and found this.

The brackets indicate that these verses actually “belong” earlier in the Torah. However, they were written here to separate two unfortunate incidents: the departure from Har Sinai (10:33-34) and Bnei Yisrael’s complaints about the Mahn (35:1).

I found this text on the Bible tool app.

Rest of pic, including bottom line that did not fit in the pic above.


See also https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/87053/did-jesus-mean-daniel-924-when-he-said-to-forgive-seventy-times-seven/87059#87059  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/50157/daniel-924-27-literary-structure-of-70-week-prophecy/50161#50161

Different subject thanks

These are not "excluded" words - they do not exist in the Hebrew Bible - the bracketed words are alternate readings (different texts) of the Hebrew text that exist apart from the Masoretic text.

That's a theory, are you saying the Masoretes, didn't bracket some words?

And what's the reason for the  pattern? , what do you think?

I'm not familiar with your Bible app, but if it's worth using at all it will have an explanation of what the brackets mean. I think @Dottard's guess is a good one, that they represent different textual readings.

@PeterKirkpatrick It's not a guess, the BH4 introduction clearly explains that the square brackets mean the words were not in the original text. I don't know what tool the question asker is using, but the explanation is surely there too, somewhere.

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory, I'm trying to understand what is the basis of your question, but can't get anything except your doubts, suspicion, and "we are (pre)doomed" feelings. Maybe you should try to see your struggle from another angle. You ask: 'is the scripture wrested?' - while pointing out one of its prophetic verses that for all times were extremely difficult. But you still can apply that same question to other things, Jesus' actual teaching, for example. Are his words wrested too?

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory, and if not, and you feel strong care about the question you have, — then you should dedicate at least couple of years for sobermind research of Daniel 9:24, from many angles and connections, because that would be fair at its smallest least. You can start from searching about backstory of hebrew electronic bible and how we get where we are using bible apps now.

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory, okay, give me the exact page number in Leningrad Codex Photobook where I can see brackets and parentheses. And please, don't say that you meant something else under "brackets" and "parentheses".

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory, no, I'm not letting you that, because you asking about what you don't know by your own. You don't know who edited that, and you're guessing about what he thought. I prefer facts. The one fact I know for sure is that brackets and parentheses are commonly used among translators and publishers for different reasons. One of these reasons specifically among ancient literature translators is exactly textual variants, that were found in different manuscripts of a same text.

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory, there's nothing underhand here. It's simply about tools used for studying ancient texts. The tools used can vary slightly depending on the text, but all good modern books will have an introduction telling you exactly what principles are being used. You can read them, you can study them, and you can make up your own mind.

@ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory, in modern editions it is, I think, always a compilation of manuscript variants that present editors met. Masoretes as I know did not used that simply because they needed a single consistent invariable text, so they tried to keep it. What Masoretes did use in some cases, is side-noting. But these side-notes are never being compiled by modern editors together with main text. Electronic hebrew bibles generally exclude these side-notes at all, mostly because their total amount is thrice+ more than the bible itself.

The brackets and parentheses happen in the Tanakh.
